# Use imports with docker compose and calling containers within container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, import, microservices

I am new to docker and still a little confused by it, so i have the following structure in my project (its a microservice type of project)

```
ODS 
-mqtt_subscriber
   __init.py
   mosquitto_subscriber.py
   Dockerfile
   requirements.py
-python_can
   __init.py
   can_logger.py
   Dockerfile
   requirements.py
__init__.py
docker-compose.yml
```

What I want to do is have several different containers, right now I have ** python_can** container. I also have a main container **mqtt_subscriber** from where I will call the containers to start running when an mqtt signal is 1 and stop on 0 (the containers will be called in the python script).

This is the dockerfile for python_can (its the same for mosquitto_subscriber except for the paths):

```
# Use the Ubuntu 20.04 image as a parent image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Set environment variables for non-interactive installation
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update and install required packages
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip && \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set the working directory within the container
WORKDIR /app
# Copy the requirements file into the container
COPY ./python_can/requirements.txt .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code into the container
COPY ./python_can/ /app/python_can/

# Specify the command to run your Python script
CMD ["python3", "./python_can/can_logger.py", "&"]
```

This is my docker-compose.yml (should i keep the python_can container here since it is still called in the mosquitto_subscriber? this is what also confuses me):

```
version: '3'
services:
  mqtt_subscriber: #main container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./mqtt_subscriber/Dockerfile
    network_mode: "host"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  python_can:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./python_can/Dockerfile
    network_mode: "host" 
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I have a Can_log_microservice class in the can_logger.py (this is a container), i want to import it in mosquitto_subscriber.py so I can change some flags from the main container script, which in turn will make the can_logger to stop logging can, but when I run the docker-compose it says that it cant find the module (it does work if I run normally the scripts, not with docker) i have used import os for this i used this code, but with docker is not working:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/ODS/')
from python_can.can_logger import Can_log_microservice.
```

What can I do so I have the same paths for everything and import my modules normally with **init**.py with from ... import ..., i have a requirements.txt for each container since in the future I want to just call certian containers so I dont need the libraries from every container.

And also how can i make python_can a conainer without putting it in docker-compose since I will already be calling it through the mqtt_subscriber python script. (this is since docker-compose runs all containers at the same time)

I dont know if this all makes sense, please help :(

I honestly don't know what to try since I have separate containers so I know that one container doesnt know the path for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Add to python path.

```
COPY ./python_can/ /app/python_can/
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app/python_can/
CMD ["python3", "./python_can/can_logger.py"]
```

Also, I believe `&` is a mistake.

Consider using python image.